# ReferenceError: Cannot access mock before initialization when using vitest

Tags: typescript, vitest

On the top of my test file, I have:

```
const setExMock = vi.fn()
```

Then I mock the Redis module (which works)

```
vi.mock('redis', () => {
  return {
    createClient: () => {
      return {
        connect: vi.fn(),
        get: vi.fn(),
        setEx: setExMock,
      }
    },
  }
})
```

Then I get the error:

> ReferenceError: Cannot access 'setExMock' before initialization

Why I'm doing this? Because I want to check on my tests if `setExMock` was called with some parameters.

I know that vitest hoistes the mock, but how can I do this? I looked at the documentation and haven't found anything.

Comment: Test runners in general don't run your code the "normal" way. If you think about what's involved in mocking a module, you realize they *can't*: they have to inject the mock at the "resolve imports" stage, which comes before the "run the code" stage of execution. Which means that a mock from the "run the code" stage of execution *can't* be used in the "resolve the imports" stage. The way you deal with that (at least in Jest, which has the same limitation for presumably the same reason) is that you import the mocked thing in the test.

Comment: It makes sense to me. At work we use Jest and this kind of approach works, I'm wondering how to do similar with vitest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution, it is necessary to wrap into a hoisted method

```
const { setExMock } = vi.hoisted(() => {
  return { setExMock: vi.fn() }
})
```

Comment: Omg, that works! why? how?

Comment: It is because Vitest works different from Jest, it basically turns your code into JS, and in this process, the variables may be out of order. With vi.hoisted, it is guaranteed that will be hoisted.